# How can I output specific data from an associative array in PHP with foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach, associative-array

My associative array:

```
$products = array();
$products[101] = array(
    "name" => "Red Shirt",
    "img" => "img/shirts/shirt-101.jpg",
    "price" => 18
);
$products[102] = array(
    "name" => "Black Shirt",
    "img" => "img/shirts/shirt-102.jpg",
    "price" => 20
);
$products[103] = array(
    "name" => "Blue Shirt",
    "img" => "img/shirts/shirt-103.jpg",    
    "price" => 20
);
```

So lets say I wanted to output the name of ALL products array like so:

> Red Shirt, Black Shirt, Blue Shirt

how can I achieve that with a foreach loop? I have tried to output only a specific key from all arrays at once but I cannot seem to do it without outputting all the keys.

Also lets say I wanted to just output the "price" of a certain array like $products[103] how can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use below code, with using `foreach`

```
foreach($products as $pro)
{
    echo $pro['name'];
}
```

above code will print only `name` key of the product array

to get price of `$product['103']` you can use like below code

```
foreach ($products as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key == '103')
    {
        echo $pro['price'];
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : to get array of names

```
$names = array();
foreach ($products as $pro)
{
    $names[] = $pro['name'];
}
print_r($names);
```

it will return

> Array ( [0] => Red Shirt [1] => Black Shirt [2] => Blue Shirt )

let me know if this helped you

Comment: Very nice thanks a ton, just curious though lets say you wanted to get the keys AND the values.. like `"name" "Red Shirt", "name" "Black Shirt", "name" "Blue Shirt",` of all arrays how can that be done?

Comment: @LucasSantos how can an array have same keys?? the word `key` means its unique... it can't be duplicate.... if same named key is there in array than it will override the last value...

Answer (score 1):

Simple,Use like this

```
foreach($products as $product){
    echo $product['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach($products as $key => $val) {
    // For name
    echo $val['name'];

    // For specific product price
    if($key == 103) {
        echo $val['price'];
    }
}
```

Let me know, if there is any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code **(This will cover all scenarios)**:

```
function getMyArray($key, $arr = array()){
    $result = array();
    foreach($arr as $arrVal){
        $result[] = $arrVal[$key];
    }
    return implode(", ", $result);
}

echo getMyArray('name', $products);  // Red Shirt, Black Shirt, Blue Shirt
echo getMyArray('img', $products);   //path1, path2, path3
echo getMyArray('price', $products); // 18, 20, 20
```

If you want some particular value:

```
echo $products[103]['price']; // 20
```

Comment: Nice way of using a function to implode the results as an array

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
foreach ($products as $prd) {
        echo $prd['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$productNames = array();
foreach($products as $key=>$product) {
    $productNames[] = $product['name'];
}

//all names with comma

echo implode(',',$productNames);
echo "\n";

//only price of $products[103]

echo $products[103]['price'];
```

**Result:**

```
Red Shirt, Black Shirt, Blue Shirt
20
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get exact the same out put as you wished by this code

```
foreach($products as $key=>$result)
{

    echo $result['name'].', ';
}
```

Out put :

```
Red Shirt, Black Shirt, Blue Shirt
```